# Create Vector-Tiles with Node-Mapnik + PostGIS (500 (Internal Server Error))

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps-api-3, postgis, mapnik

I'm trying to create web maps with vector-tile in google map. I'm using :

1. `mapnik`
2. `node.js`
3. `node-mapnik`
4. `postGIS`

i use port 8000 (127.0.0.1:8000) to appear the map-tile

```
var mapTiles = {
    tilejson: '1.0.0',
    scheme: 'xyz',
    tiles: ['127.0.0.1:8000/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'],
    formatter: function(options, data) { return data.NAME }
};
```

And i have `server.js`, this file i use to create server.

```
    http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  parseXYZ(req, TMS_SCHEME, function(err,params) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.end(err.message);
    } else {
      try {
        var map = new mapnik.Map(256, 256, mercator.proj4);
        var layer = new mapnik.Layer('tile', mercator.proj4);
        var postgis = new mapnik.Datasource(postgis_settings); // settings defined above
        var bbox = mercator.xyz_to_envelope(parseInt(params.x),
                                               parseInt(params.y),
                                               parseInt(params.z), false); // coordinates provided by the sphericalmercator.js script
        layer.datasource = postgis; 
        layer.styles = ['polygon']; // this pertains the the style in the xml doc
        map.bufferSize = 0; // how much edging is provided for each tile rendered
        map.load(path.join(__dirname, 'tile_symbols.xml'), {strict: true}, function(err,map) {
            if (err) throw err;
            map.add_layer(layer);
            map.extent = bbox;
            var im = new mapnik.Image(map.width, map.height);
            map.render(im, function(err, im) {
              if (err) {
                throw err;
              } else {
                res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png'});
                res.end(im.encodeSync('png'));
              }
            }); 
        });

      }
      catch (err) {
        res.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end(err.message);
      }
    }
  });
}).listen(port);
```

After that i start the service `> node server.js` i get success message `server running on port 8000`. Then i'm trying to check my code work or not, and i found some problem :

1. I try to access 127.0.0.1:8000 i get `no x,y,z provided`
2. if i access the `index.html` file (`http://localhost/webmaps/`), the
   polygon doesn't appear in map and i get `500 (Internal Server Error)` - `Could not create datasource for type: 'postgis' (no datasource plugin directories have been successfully registered)`

Could someone help me to fix this problem ? or if someone have another way to make vector-tile for huge data in google maps, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Looks like you need to register postgis as a plugin. Look at example code in `node-mapnik` on github for the register datasource lines.

Comment: Ever figure this one out @Adi ?

Comment: Yeah, @Adi, any luck? I just asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42960495/2399799)